# Regular Expressions - Parsing Domain Issues

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the domain -- everything but the subdomain.

I have this regexp right now:

```
(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*([-a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})){1,2}
```

This works for things like:

```
domain.tld
subdomain.tld
```

But it runs into trouble with tld's like ".com.au" or ".co.uk":

```
domain.co.uk (finds co.uk, should find domain.co.uk)
subdomain.domain.co.uk (finds co.uk, should find domain.co.uk)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: text1.text2.text3 could be subdomain.domain.suffix or it could be domain.suffixPart1.suffixPart2.  Regex alone is not the answer.

Comment: @Mitch -- I didn't list it because I didn't think it was relevant, as I can make it work. I use PHP, but can transpose regex from any language to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this problem is "reasonably solvable"; Mozilla maintains [a list of 'public suffix' domains](http://publicsuffix.org/list/) that is intended to help browser authors accept cookies for only domains within one administrative control (e.g., prevent someone from setting a cookie valid for `*.co.uk.` or `*.union.aero.`). It obviously isn't perfect (near the end, you'll find a long list of `is-a-caterer.com`-style domains, so `foo.is-a-caterer.com` couldn't set a cookie that would be used by `bar.is-a-caterer.com`, but `is-a-caterer.com` is perfectly well a "domain" as you've defined it.)

So, if you're prepared to use the list as provided, you could write a quick little parser that would know how to apply the general rules and exceptions to determine where in the given input string your "domain" comes, and return just the portion you're interested in.

I think simpler approaches are doomed to failure: some [ccTLDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cctld) such as `.ca` don't use second-level domains, some such as `.br` use dozens, and some, like `lib.or.us` are several levels away from the "domain" such as `multnomah.lib.or.us`. Unless you're using curated lists of which domains are a public suffix, you're doomed to being wrong for some non-trivial set of input strings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll either try to find one that already exists or make my own :)